# Using "Is Null" as a criteria based on a form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, criteria

I'm trying to get my query to only return null records if a radio box on a form is ticked. If I manually include the criteria Is Null in the query it works just fine, and elsewhere things like

```
IIf([Forms]![Reports]![Status - Active]=True,"Active")
```

work just fine.

However,

```
IIf([Forms]![Reports]![Status - Null]=True,"Is Null")
```

just ignores it (I assume because it's actually looking for the text "Is Null" rather than null records) and

```
IIf([Forms]![Reports]![Status - Null]=True,Is Null)
```

fails because it's too complex. Is there any way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could work around in a couple of ways, for example.

```
SELECT t.atext
FROM Table1 t
WHERE IsNull([atext])=[Forms]![Reports]![Status - Null]
```

BTW, Immediate If (IIf) takes three arguments.