# How to simulate "is null" query criteria based on checkbox control value

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

I have similar problem as this question
[Using "Is Null" as a criteria based on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413987/using-is-null-as-a-criteria-based-on-a-form)

Unfortunately the accepted answer there is not applicable in my case. I need to simulate "is null" criteria based on control value. Is there any other way or only the answer provided in that question?

What I did so far is created a checkbox control and label it "Remove Null Values" with default value null

then on the criteria of the query I place [Forms]![TempUI]![chkRemoveNoDate]

When I run the query, it does not show items with null values. I am hoping that it will show null items because the default value of the checkbox is null

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two criteria:

```
where forms!tempUI!ckRemoveNoDate and myField is null
```

or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

In the GUI designer, on the first criteria line have:

```
[Forms]![TempUI]![chkRemoveNoDate]
```

and on the next criteria line (which makes an "OR") have:

```
Is Null
```